# Initializing New Class With Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Can someone explain the differences between these three declarations.

`Animal var = new Dog()`

`Dog var = new Dog()`

`Dog var = new Animal()`

The second declaration is most used, but I don't understand what role the left class has vs the right class, or when you use one vs the other.

The assumption is Dog extends Animal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "type on the right" (`Dog`) is the actual type of the instance being created. 
It must be a real class (not an interface). 
This class defines the "real, implemented behavior" of the new object.

The "type on the left" (`Animal`) is the type of the variable being used to store the reference to the instance being created. 
The "type on the left" must be an ancestor class/interface of the "class on the right" (otherwise you have to do a cast). 
Using this variable (without casts), you will only have access to the properties/methods of `Animal` (no additional properties/methods of `Dog`), and you may assume that *the contract of `Animal` is implemented,* without knowing any of the details, which you would know if the type was `Dog`.

This is very basic polymorphism, please read a tutorial/book on this to get more insight.

Here is a small example:

```
Animal a1 = new Animal(); // works
Animal a2 = new Dog(); // works, Dog a subtype of animal
Dog d1 = new Animal(); // does not work, Animal not a subtype of Dog
a1 = a2; // works
d1 = a1; // doesn't work

// If Dog has a function "bark" and Animal has a function "breathe"
a1.breathe(); // works
d1.breathe(); // works
d1.bark(); // works
a1.bark(); // does not compile, Animal not always a Dog
```

*See it like this:* All `Dog`s are `Animal`s, so you can assign a `Dog` value to an `Animal` variable. But not all `Animal`s are `Dog`s, so you can not assign all `Animal`s to a variable of type `Dog`.

Comment: So you're saying that Animal var = new Dog() means it is an instance of type Dog but only has the access to the members of Animal?

Comment: @atg, yes this is correct, you will only have access to members of class `Ànimal` through `var`. You can use **casts** to access the `Dog` methods though: `((Dog) var).bark()`. But this should be avoided whenever possible. If you need access to the methods specific to `Dog` (but not `Animal`), just declare the variable as `Dog var = ...`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going into my senior year and I thought it would be good to reread a java book over the summer to solidify my knowledge I haven't gotten to the chapter that deals with polymorphism, but a coworker who has started learning java asked me a related question. I knew it had to do with polymorphism but I didn't know enough to explain the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dog is a specific animal. Therefore you can call Dog animal.
2. Of course a dog is a dog.
3. An animal is probably not a dog, it can be a cat, a mouse etc. Therefore you can't use this way.